# Python, tuple index out of range

Tags: image, python-2.7, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I want to display an image in my root window, but it says

> IndexError: tuple index out of range

Do you know what's wrong?
Here's my code:

```
import numpy
import cv2
from Tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

root = Tk()#

lena = "C:\lena.jpg"

#convert jpg
image = Image.open(lena)
photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)


w = Canvas(root)
w.create_image( image = photo)
w.pack()


root.mainloop()
```

Error message:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>         File "C:\Users\Marrin\Desktop\Uni\EPR\ImagineEditor_EPR9\openImageInTkinter.py", line 16, in 
>           w.create_image( image = photo)
>         File "C:\Users\Marrin\Anaconda2\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 2314, in create_image
>           return self._create('image', args, kw)
>         File "C:\Users\Marrin\Anaconda2\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 2298, in _create
>           cnf = args[-1]
>       IndexError: tuple index out of range

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use Tkinter.Canvas.create_image without specifying the coordinates. In order to make your example work as intended, you must specify the coordinates where your image is placed; keep in mind that such coordinates refer to the center of your image.

About your example, you could do something like this:

```
w = Canvas(root)
w.pack()
w.create_image(0, 0, image=photo, anchor="nw")
```

Please note that I've also specified a "North-West" anchoring, so that the (0, 0) coordinate refers to the top/leftmost point of your image (the default anchoring refers to the central point of the image).

Comment: ahh now i understand !

Answer (score 0):

`create_image` required position as first argument

http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm#Tkinter.Canvas.create_image-method